# Using the read function in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

I'm unsure how to correctly get the read function to do what I want it do. I want it to cycle it through a list of characters in a file until it reaches the character "#". I want it to look at each character, and if it is a vowel to append it to a list. The documentation of the read function I have seen in other help threads confuses me. So far I have this:

```
def opt():
    filename = input("Enter the name of your input file: ")
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    a = []
    vowel = infile.read(1)
    while (vowel != '#'):
        if vowel == "A":
            a.append(vowel)
            vowel = infile.read(1)
        elif vowel == "E":
            a.append(vowel)
            vowel = infile.read(1)
        elif vowel == "I":
            a.append(vowel)
            vowel = infile.read(1)
        elif vowel == "O":
            a.append(vowel)
            vowel = infile.read(1)
        elif vowel == "U":
            a.append(vowel)
            vowel = infile.read(1)
        else:
            vowel = infile.read(1)
    return (a)
```

Note the else operator, if it is a consonant - it'll just go to the next character.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `.read()` with no parameter *reads the entire file* - there's no point putting that in a loop, as there will be nothing left to read.  You want `.read(1)` to get a single character.

Comment: I had this before, but when I switch all the .read() s to .read(1) my list only has the vowel A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would do like this

```
def opt():
    filename = input("Enter the name of your input file: ")
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    a = []
    vowel = infile.read(1)
    while vowel != '#':
        if vowel in ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'):
            a.append(vowel)
        vowel = infile.read(1)
    return a
```

Comment: Can you show your file content and your expected output?

Comment: I solved the issue. the stuff I have in OP is correct, I just wasn't account for lowercase (silly me)..